# Error querying messages by its rfc822msgid

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get a message by its Message-ID. The Gmail API has no **get()** method to pass the Message-ID in, so I have to **list()** first passing the **q** parameter as given below:

```
q="rfc822msgid:%s" % message_id
```

The response brings a list with a single message, just as hoped. Then I use the **get()** method to retrieve the message by its *Google style* identifier. This works like a charm, unless the Message-ID contains a **+** character:

```
message_id="a+b@c"
```

In this case, the Google Api Client requests this URL:

```
url="https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=rfc822msgid%3Aa+b%40c&alt=json"
```

I think the client is doing a **quote_plus()** with **safe="+"** to avoid the encoding of the **+** character. But this causes a problem in the commented cases, because the server interprets the **+** character as an space one, so the Message-ID is no more valid:

```
message_id="a b@c"
```

I tried to switch the **+** character for its quoted representation (**%2B**), but when the client encodes the URL, the Message-ID becomes quite worst due to the **quote(quote())**:

```
message_id="a%252Bb%40c"
```

So, is there a way to send the **+** character avoiding the server to decode it as a space character?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I was working on the solutions commented here with no positive result. But since a few days ago, my original code started to work. I've not changed a single line, so I think Google has fixed something related this. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on: I think the client is doing a quote_plus() with safe="+"?  What client are you using, can you not view code/update it?

Comment: I am using [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/), the one recommended by Google. I do `client = build("gmail", "v1")` to instance the Gmail API client, and then `client.users().list()`, just as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), to search for the messages. But the `build()` method creates the client dynamically and I cannot find where/how the API requests are done.

Comment: I tested some string encoding / quotation by myself, and found that `urllib.quote_plus("", safe="+")` satisfies the Google client implementation, but I'm not sure if this is the way it does; it's only a guess.

Comment: Have you tried making it url-safe by yourself? Replace all `+` with  `-` and all `/` with `_` before encoding it.

Comment: The bug was gone by itself; I think Google has fixed something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @vermicida Did you get a bug report confirmation number or just had to trust?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext I've not worked on this code since those days (almost 4 years), but I think it was a one-time error. It didn't take long to get resolved, so I never reported it.

Answer (score 0):

URLEncoder.encode("+", "UTF-8"); yields "%2B"

replace "+" with query parameter. ie

URLEncoder.encode("rfc822msgid:", "UTF-8");

Comment: The bug was gone by itself; I think Google has fixed something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @vermicida Did you get a bug report confirmation number or just had to trust?